# get range from the nearest number in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, range

I have one range object and another is price_values array, now I want to nearest range from the range object for each value of price_values array. I have tried the below solution but it's not given me the proper range.

```
range = {
    0: '25-500',
    1: '1500-2500',
    2: '5000-10000'
}

let price_values = [5, 100, 1500, 7000, 15000]
```

**I tired below solution**

```
    let nearestPriceRangeArr = [];
let rangeLength = Object.keys(range).length;
Object.keys(range).forEach(key => {
    price_values.forEach((price, qKey) => {
        let rangeArr = key.split("-");
        let fromRange = parseInt(rangeArr[0]);
        let toRange = parseInt(rangeArr[1]);
        if(price <= fromRange) {
            if(x == 0) {
                nearestPriceRangeArr[price] = key;
            }
        } else {
            if (price >= fromRange && price <= toRange) {
                nearestPriceRangeArr[price] = key;
            } else {
                if(price >= toRange) {
                let ab = (x == rangeLength - 1) ? key : key;
                    nearestPriceRangeArr[price] = ab;
                }
            }
        }
        x++;
    });
});
```

**Expected Output**

```
nearestPriceRangeArr[5] = '25-500';
nearestPriceRangeArr[100] = '25-500';
nearestPriceRangeArr[1500] = '1500-2500';
nearestPriceRangeArr[7000] = '5000-10000';
nearestPriceRangeArr[15000] = '5000-10000';
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Do you have to store the range as a string? Storing an object with a `min` and `max` number removes the need for any string parsing.

Comment: @NinaScholz added expected output

Comment: what about values like `3000`, `3750` or `4000`?

Comment: they will be fall into 5000-10000 range

Comment: @DBS I stored range as a string

Answer (score 3):

You could take an array of ranges and find the range by checking the price.

```js
const
    range = ['25-500', '1500-2500', '5000-10000'],
    prices = [5, 100, 1500, 7000, 15000],
    result = Object.fromEntries(prices.map(p => [p, range.find((r, i, { length }) => {
        const [low, high] = r.split('-').map(Number);
        return p <= high || i === length - 1;
    })]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can we make a key of each price_values which I mentioned in expected output

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what I did, but its strange solution for your strange problem.

```
console.clear();
let range = {
    0: '25-500',
    1: '1500-2500',
    2: '5000-10000'
}
let price_values = [5, 100, 1500, 7000, 15000];
let nearestPriceRangeArr = {};
let rangeValues = Object.values(range);

price_values.forEach((price)=>{
  // for prices which are in one the range_values
  rangeValues.forEach((range, rangeIndex)=>{
    let ranges = range.split('-');
    if(price >= parseInt(ranges[0]) && price <= parseInt(ranges[1])){
      nearestPriceRangeArr = {
        ...nearestPriceRangeArr,
       [price] : range
      }
    }
    /* if price is not falling in any range */
    // if price is smaller than first range
    if(rangeIndex === 0){
        if(price <= ranges[0]){
          nearestPriceRangeArr = {
          ...nearestPriceRangeArr,
         [price] : range
        }
      }
    } else {
      // if price is greater than previous range
      // and smaller than current range
      const previousRanges = rangeValues[rangeIndex - 1].split("-");
      if(price > previousRanges[1] && price <= ranges[0] ){
         nearestPriceRangeArr = {
          ...nearestPriceRangeArr,
         [price] : range
        }
      } else {
        // if price is greater than last range
        if(price > ranges[1]){
            nearestPriceRangeArr = {
            ...nearestPriceRangeArr,
           [price] : range
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })  
})

console.log(nearestPriceRangeArr);
console.log(nearestPriceRangeArr[5])
console.log(nearestPriceRangeArr[100])
console.log(nearestPriceRangeArr[1500])
console.log(nearestPriceRangeArr[7000])
console.log(nearestPriceRangeArr[15000])
```

[image: results screenshot]